# openapi-generator and "ignoring complex example on request body" message

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator

I use the org.openapi.generator gradle plugin (version 6.2.1) and when I generate spring codes from my openapi.yml file I have the follow message "Ignoring complex example on request body". I don't understand why, someone have an idea ?

Here is an exerpt of my openapi.yml file :

```
paths:
  "/test":
    post:
      summary: ...
      tags:
        - ...
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/json:
            schema:
              type: array
              items:
                $ref: ...
            examples:
              example1:
                value: [
                  {
                    ...
                  }
                ]
```

Thanks for your help

I don't find solution

Comment: The message you are receiving is from the openapi java code generator in their repo.  In short, they prevent examples of complex models in certain situations.  Perhaps you could raise the issue there?  https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/AbstractJavaCodegen.java#L1229

Comment: I already see this code but I don't understand how I resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that it is not implemented/supported yet: you cannot get rid of the warning (unless suppressing WARN logging).

The code generation still works and you can use the generated `spring` application.